# Locally free sheaves and ext sheaf

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a locally free sheaf of rank $r$ in $X = \mathbb{P}^{n}$. 
It´s true that $\mathscr{ext}^{i}(\mathcal{F}, O_{X}) = 0$ for each $i\geq 1$?

Comment: What you say is correct.

Comment: We can show this using the resolution :  $0 \longrightarrow \mathcal{F} \longrightarrow \mathcal{F} \longrightarrow 0$?